# When to use GPTJModel and when to use GPTJForCausalLM?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

While using the [from_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.11.3/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained) model loading function, what is the difference between using [GPTJModel](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.11.3/model_doc/gptj.html#gptjmodel) or [GPTJForCausalLM](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.11.3/model_doc/gptj.html#gptjforcausallm) ?

Their documentation mentions

> The bare GPT-J Model transformer outputting raw hidden-states without
> any specific head on top.

for `GPTJModel` model

and

> The GPT-J Model transformer with a language modeling head on top
> (linear layer with weights tied to the input embeddings).

for `GPTJForCausalLM`

What does that difference mean in general, also specifically if the user wants to further finetune the model ?